# Method listener

Tags: java, android, methods

I have this method which receives data from a db:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> scaricaDatiUtente(){

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, DatiNet.MostraDati, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            System.out.println(response.toString());

            try {
                JSONArray utenti = response.getJSONArray("utenti");

                for (int i = 0; i < utenti.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject student = utenti.getJSONObject(i);
                    ArrayList<String> studentdata = new ArrayList<String>();
                    studentdata.add(student.getString("nome"));
                    studentdata.add(student.getString("cognome"));
                    studentdata.add(student.getString("numero"));
                    studentdata.add(student.getString("email"));

                    result.add(studentdata);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.append(error.getMessage());

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    return result;
}
```

The problem is that the result is returned before data is downloaded.
How can make it wait for data and then return?

Comment: It seems you are trying to access (and return) the results before they have finished been retrieved. You want to implement a call back to do what you want when you know you have finished grabbing the results. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28120209/3899529

Comment: Actually https://gist.github.com/hhfa1990/077d46201ecee111e356 is probably a nicer example.

Comment: i have an error " cannot resolve symbol callback"

Comment: Yes, you have to declare what "callback" is. Please see the links I posted above.

Comment: I saw them but I can not understand how ...

Comment: ok, well I suggest working through something like this first: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800