# Android Volley return value from response

Tags: android, android-volley

How do I get the response out of onResponse so that I can return it? I have found this but I don't really understand how to implement it for me. [How can I return value from function onResponse of Volley?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120029/how-can-i-return-value-from-function-onresponse-of-volley)

I hope there is an updated method or something easier that I might have missed 
This is my code

```
public Boolean checkIfPersonExists(Context context, final Person aPerson){
        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, USEREXISTS, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("RESPONSE",response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("email",aPerson.getEmail());
                params.put("phone",aPerson.getPhone());
                return params;
            }
        };
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(postRequest);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You will return nothing. But call a function with `response` as parameter. That functions handles the ... response.

Comment: But I can't call another function as checkIfPersonExists is called from an Activity. checkIfPersonExists sits in another class.

Comment: You should implement that as an interface as described in the link which you do not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was mentioned, you need to implement interface and get a callback

Create a new interface like this

```
public interface GeneralCallbacks {
void VolleyResponse(String data);
}
```

Implement the interface on your activity class

```
public class YourActivity implements ScoreboardCallback
{
    @Override
    public void VolleyResponse(String data)
    {
      //do stuff with data
    }
}
```

And finally changing your response function to something like this

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            ((GeneralCallbacks)context).VolleyResponse(response); // This will make a callback to activity.
            aPerson.SomeFunction(); // This will call person's function
            Log.d("RESPONSE",response.toString());
        }
```

Comment: Sorry just to clarify, can you show me an example of the code being called elsewhere? How do I call the response out if it needs a parameter?

Comment: Ive fixed some error on the code. So, Do you want to make a call to aPerson or callback to activity? or where?