# LatLng Arraylist is not returning in onReponse() Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am getting a list of latitude and longitude using volley from my server. Here is the function.

```
private List<LatLng> getLocations() {
    final List<LatLng> pos = new ArrayList<>();
    StringRequest rqst = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://www.findandgo.in/server/getAllUsersLocation.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    Double lat = Double.parseDouble(object.getString("user_latitude"));
                    Double longi = Double.parseDouble(object.getString("user_longitude"));
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat,longi);
                    pos.add(latLng);
//here the list is returning size
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        rq.add(rqst);
        //here the list is showing size 0
        return pos;
    }
```

The above function is returning null list but when I use log value in onResponse to see if the value is present, it shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) is asynchronous by nature, therefore expecting a sequential flow here is not right. See what the documentation says -

> Strong ordering that makes it easy to correctly populate your UI with
>   data fetched **asynchronously** from the network.

The onResponse() method is called when your client receives a server response after successful POST.

When you are returning your list "pos" (at the end of the method body), it is empty because at that point of time the server has not yet received a list of lat-long values.

Therefore, you must return the list in onResponse(), so that the populated list is returned to the caller function when server response is received.

```
try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    Double lat = Double.parseDouble(object.getString("user_latitude"));
                    Double longi = Double.parseDouble(object.getString("user_longitude"));
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat,longi);
                    pos.add(latLng);
//here the list is returning size
                    }
return pos; //return list here (since list is populated now)

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

This however is not exactly the best approach, since the server might take time to send a response. Thus, make sure your UI handles this delay accordingly (show a ProgressDialog in the meantime).

**EDIT** - since you cannot return List<> from onResponse, you can use a Callback interfaces as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120029/how-can-i-return-value-from-function-onresponse-of-volley).

Sample code using Callback Interfaces -

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    coordinates = parseLocation(response);
    if((coordinates == null && coordinates.isEmpty())||coordinates.equals("NOT_VALID_ADDRESS")) {
        showAlert("Please Enter A Valid Zip Code");
    } else {
        useCoordinates(coordinates);
    }
}
Then implement the method that uses the coordinates:

public void useCoordinates(Location coordinates) {
    // Use the value
}
```

Comment: But if i try to return from onResponse(), it shows 
Cannot return a value from a method with void result type

Comment: Thanks, bro. You saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that outside the volley class you will never get a result. Because it is asynchronous. use call back functions to get result to it or use code in that volley method

```
private void getLocations() {
    final List<LatLng> pos = new ArrayList<>();
    StringRequest rqst = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://www.findandgo.in/server/getAllUsersLocation.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    Double lat = Double.parseDouble(object.getString("user_latitude"));
                    Double longi = Double.parseDouble(object.getString("user_longitude"));
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat,longi);
                    pos.add(latLng);


                    }
                    //do your code here
                    SomthingFunction(pos); call a function

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        rq.add(rqst);

    }
```