# Android Volley StringRequest passing response to MainActivity

Tags: java, android, post, android-volley

**Need to get the response in MainActivity**

> MyVolleyClass.java

```
public class MyVolleyClass  {
    Context context;

    public String stringResponse()
    {

        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLManager.BASE_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                //need to return this response to my main activity



            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        MySingleton.getInstance(context).addTorequestque(stringRequest);


        return "";   //whenever a response is got i need to return the response from the server to main activity


    }

}

> MainActivity.java


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//expecting the string returned from the MyVolleyClass.java
        String response=new DataFetcherVolley(getApplicationContext()).dataFetch();
        Toast.makeText(this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
    }
}
```

1. I just need the string response from MyVolleyClass to my MainActivity
2. Please make some changes in MyVolleyClass
3. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a callback to pass the response from your volley class to the main activity. Please take a look at this SO post from a while back :
[How can I return value from function onResponse of Volley?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120029/how-can-i-return-value-from-function-onresponse-of-volley)