# How do I get return value onResponse

Tags: java, android

I know this is the answer, but I couldn't add it to my code.

[How can I return value from function onResponse of Volley?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120029/how-can-i-return-value-from-function-onresponse-of-volley)
<------

like here I created interface.
I did it all. 
I just don't know how to convert this my code to it, and how to use the return value in other activities.

```
    public void priceDate(Context contex, final String coin) {

    String URL = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/exchanges/full?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&api_key=" + apiKey;


    //String a =
   //json_Parser = new JSONParser(_usd);

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(contex);



    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            //Log.d("Main",response.toString());}
            DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
                String yourFormattedString = formatter.format(100000);
                try {
                    JSONObject Data = response.getJSONObject("Data");
                    JSONObject AggregatedData = Data.getJSONObject("AggregatedData");

                    try {

                        String Price = AggregatedData.getString("PRICE");

                        String formatPrice = formatter.format(Math.round(Float.valueOf(Price)));


                        _price.setText("Price :" + formatPrice);


                    } catch (Error e) {
                        _price.setText("Data Not Avvaliable");

                    }


                try {

                    String Open = AggregatedData.getString("OPENDAY");
                    String formatOpen = formatter.format(Math.round(Float.valueOf(Open)));
                    _open.setText("Open :" + formatOpen);


                } catch (Error e) {
                    _open.setText("Data Not Avvaliable");

                }

                try {
                    String Low = AggregatedData.getString("LOWDAY");
                    String formatLow = formatter.format(Math.round(Float.valueOf(Low)));
                    _low.setText("Low :" + formatLow);


                } catch (Error e) {
                    _low.setText("Data Not Avvaliable");

                }

                try {
                    String High = AggregatedData.getString("HIGHDAY");
                    String formatHigh = formatter.format(Math.round(Float.valueOf(High)));
                    _high.setText("High :" + formatHigh);


                } catch (Error e) {
                    _high.setText("Data Not Avvaliable");

                }

                try {
                    String Volume = AggregatedData.getString("VOLUMEDAY");
                    String formatVol = formatter.format(Math.round(Float.valueOf(Volume)));
                    _volume.setText("Volume :" + formatVol);


                } catch (Error e) {
                    _volume.setText("Data Not Avvaliable");

                }


                try {
                    String LastUpdate = AggregatedData.getString("LASTUPDATE");
                    String convert = unix_time(Long.parseLong(LastUpdate));
                    _lastUpdate.setText("Last Update :" + LastUpdate);
                } catch (Error e) {
                    _lastUpdate.setText("Data Not Avvaliable");

                }

                try {
                    String TradeId = AggregatedData.getString("LASTTRADEID");
                    _tradeId.setText("Trade Id :" + String.valueOf(Math.round(Float.parseFloat(TradeId))));


                } catch (Error e) {
                    _tradeId.setText("Data Not Avvaliable");

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }



    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using interface. Follow the below steps,

First create Interface in your application like,

```
public interface AsyncTaskListener {
    void onRequestCompleted(JSONObject result, Integer statusCode);
}
```

And implement this interface in your activity where you want make request, Assume object of your volley class is objVolley, then your request will like below

```
    public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncTaskListener {
        public void priceDate(YourActivity.this, coin, YourActivity.this);
    }
```

Then Your volley class and method like this,

```
    public class PostDataHelper {
        public void priceDate(Context contex, final String coin, final AsyncTaskListener asyncTaskListener) {
@Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
               asyncTaskListener.onRequestCompleted(response, 200);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             asyncTaskListener.onRequestCompleted(response, 200);
        }
    });
      }
    }
```

Hope this will help you, Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Your volley code is embedded into your activity code so there isn't much advantage to creating a interface.

You need to create a separate class for handling volley requests.

```
public class VolleyRequest {
    VolleyCallback mResultCallback;
    RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    public VolleyRequest(VolleyCallback resultCallback, Context context){
        mResultCallback = resultCallback;
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    }

    public void cancelRequests(String TAG){
        if(mRequestQueue != null){
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(TAG);
        }
    }

    public void volleyGetRequest(String url, final String TAG) {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                if (mResultCallback != null) {
                    mResultCallback.onSuccess(response, TAG);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (mResultCallback != null) {
                    mResultCallback.onError(error, TAG);
                }
            }
        });
        jsonObjectRequest.setTag(TAG);
        mRequestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

Then create a interface class to handle the callbacks

```
public interface VolleyCallback {
    void onSuccess(JSONObject response, String tag);
    void onError(VolleyError error, String tag);
}
```

Then in your activity class

```
private void initvolley(){
        VolleyCallback volleyCallback = new VolleyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONObject response, String tag) {
                switch (tag){
                    //add response handling code here
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VolleyError error, String tag) {
                //handle error response here
            }
        };
        VolleyRequest volleyRequest = new VolleyRequest(volleyCallback, this);
        String URL = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/exchanges/full?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&api_key=" + apiKey;
        volleyRequest.volleyGetRequest(URL, request_tag/*Request tag incase you have multiple requests in same activity*/);
    }
```